# apache - redirect not found file/directory to index.php while maintaining URL and query string

Tags: apache

I'm using apache web (2.4.6) server with PHP (7.2.27) and I'm trying to redirect all not found directory and file to domain root, which point to `index.php`.

So when I query these URL for example: `https://example.com/file?foo=bar` or `https://example.com/directory/?foo=bar`, I want that it execute my PHP script (index.php) and keep the full URL, instead of returning file not found (404). My PHP script is doing redirect process so I need to keep the `DOCUMENT_URI` and `QUERY_STRING` that I get through `$_SERVER`.

For now I only manage to do this trick and in my PHP script I can process the `q` parameter to get `DOCUMENT_URI` and `QUERY_STRING` but it's a bit ugly:

```
<Directory "/var/www/sites/example.com">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Example output with that `RewriteRule`:

- From this `https://example.com/file?foo=bar` -> `https://example.com/index.php?q=file&foo=bar`
- From this `https://example.com/directory/?foo=bar` ->  `https://example.com/index.php?q=directory/&foo=bar`

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to fix that problem. So, the rewrite:

```
<Directory "/var/www/sites/example.com">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

How to get the initial URL (before the rewrite), with the directory/file and the query string:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

// If you want to only get the path without the query string
$url = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
?>
```

> `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` includes the query string and the directory/file (e.g. file?foo=bar...) before the rewrite. Where `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_URI"]` return only the directory/file after the rewrite.